# How to access the multiple columns with index in dataframe to find a string for complete row in excel worksheet

Tags: python

Running this line:

```
if(df['Function Name'][index].find('PowerMode') !=-1):
```

I am getting the error:

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'find'
```

`df['Function Name']` column will have "Power is applied in the lower stage"

Comment: Please show us what your dataframe looks like.

Comment: My df  TestNo Keywords                                       FunctionName
0     1.0    power                                                NaN
1     NaN      NaN  Power  is applied\nPowerMode ("Value",2,3);\nC...
2     NaN      NaN                                                NaN
3     2.0    error  erro  is applied\nErrorMode ("Value",2,3);

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if(df['Function Name'].iloc[index].find('PowerMode') !=-1)
```

Update:

```
x = [[1.0, 'power', None, 1, None, None, 'Power is applied\nPowerMode', ("Value",2,3)]]
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
for index, col in df.iterrows():
    if df[6][index].find('PowerMode'):
        print(df[7][index])
```

It returns:

```
('Value', 2, 3)
```

Or:

```
df[df[6].str.contains('PowerMode')]
```

Will return all rows with the "PowerMode" text in specified column. This way you could try:

```
df[df[6].str.contains('PowerMode')][7]
```

Returning:

```
(Value, 2, 3)
```

Comment: hi, I tried , getting error AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'find', Indeed, df['function name'] has a PowerMode ("value", 23,4), I tried using  the same for "Power(", But When I Use  df['Function name'] [2].find('PowerMode') !=1, will execute without error. I need to irerate the loop with index

Comment: for index,col in df.iterrows():
    print(df['FunctionName'][index]) This code will print the column functionname and index, I need to check string like power, current, voitage in the df['functionname']

Comment: Please, provide some sample data. I will update my answer.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this, This will work, but I need to iterate the loop, I have a column = FunctionName, Each cell has multi string terminated with new line '\n', I wanna to apply condition  for each cell and iterate the row through index  as my column number is constant., I have df[FunctionName'][3], but this 3 shoulf be index through iteration of  rows,

Comment: I need to apply if condition using find function, df['FunctionName'][3].find(powermode')!=-1): Call other function   this 3 should be index , it shoul iterate rows I..e    for index,col in iteraterows: if( df['FunctionName'][index].find('powemode') != -1) : print:(" it is true")

Comment: I can us e the above statement df[df[6].str.contains('PowerMode')][7], but cannot iterate in a loop df[df[6].str.contains('PowerMode')][I+1] as it igive index out of error